# Offered bounty are excluded from daily reputation cap

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, daily-reputation-limit

I wanted to verify/confirm something about bounties so here is the situation:

1. I reached the daily reputation cap
2. I started a bounty right after to get below 200 Rep
3. Upvotes I am earning after (2) **aren't** counted.

It's like the reputation I lost when offering the bounty isn't included in the overall calculation. Is this correct? Can we say that bounties in general (earned or offered) are excluded from the equation?

It's not clearly stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

<sup>PS: I don't care about the reputation I lost or the one I am not earning. I am simply curious and wanted to verify if it's by design or a bug.</sup>

**UPDATE**

To clarify the question: I am not surprised about this behavior. I explicitly started the bounty to verify this and wanted to confirm that it's indeed the correct behavior.

Comment: If not anytime you got over 250 points you could offer what is basically a free bounty.

Comment: I mean, bounties are free anyway, the points are made up and don't matter

Comment: @RobertLongson it's not a free bounty because you lose reputation and you may not earn more later. As a side note, the +15 of accepted answer can go beyound the rep cap so we can also use them for *free* bounties

Comment: Of course they're not counted, you cannot get reputation from upvotes or edits after hitting the 200 rep limit, this is totally clear: *"You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit."* - It's not clear what the problem is

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is correct. The daily cap is from upvotes. An answer being accepted and bounties (in either direction) are not counted towards it. I can't find the detailed explanation of how this works right now.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245921

Comment: ... Which makes sense when you think about it.  You can't game the reputation cap by offering bounties.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes it make sense to me and I wanted to confirm it ;) I would be surprised if it wasn't made that way

Comment: @Nick there are also cases when you can get unpovtes or deleted answer or other negative rep that would count so I wanted to confirm it's not the case with offred bounty

Comment: The rep cap is 200 so if you are capped but would otherwise have 250 points then the 50 points would be a free bounty is my point because either way you get 200 points.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Getting rep from an answer you had downvoted being deleted isn't you gaining rep, it's you not losing rep as if the event never happened

Comment: I like that you used your own account for science ;) PS. I don't think people are reading your PS..

Comment: @Nick well, maybe it's trivial but I also faced complex cases with unaccepted answer, unupvoted answer, etc (not done the same day) that I was able to *validate* and I wondered if bounty will behave the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is accurate in terms of the site's behavior. The bounty system and reputation cap have worked this way since the beginning. See [this Q&A on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/how-does-proposing-a-bounty-affect-the-reputation-cap).

Essentially, the reputation cap is based *only* on vote-earnings-per-day, not net reputation gain. Paying a bounty has no effect on the vote-based reputation cap.

A [feature request was proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22442/reputation-cap-ignores-reputation-paid-for-bounty-offerings) to change this back in 2009, but…it wasn't implemented, and isn't likely to be.

Note that *received* bounties are different, as they completely ignore the reputation cap. Again, this makes sense, if you think of the reputation cap as being based on *vote* earnings of 200 reputation per day. The bounty amount is not included in this—it is entirely a bonus. Similarly, reputation gained from acceptance is not included in the daily reputation cap.